# Undefined symbol while importing so. file

Tags: python, python-3.x, gcc, shared-libraries, undefined-symbol

I was running a code of (https://github.com/google-deepmind/constrained_optidice) for research purpose. When I tried to run neural/run_experiments after installing the requirements as stated, it gave me an error of

`envs/cop/lib/python3.7/site-packages/courier/python/py_client.so: undefined symbol:_ZN4absl12lts_2021110214ascii_internal13kPropertyBitsE`

The code block where error arises is:

```
from courier.python import py_client
```

where courier.python is directory and **py_client is .so file.**

I tested it with ubuntu 20.04 and 22.04 but both did not work. I am not 100% sure but i saw this error arises when there is a conflict of unpackaging c-wrapped file (.so file). However, I tried with different gcc and g++, it did not work neither.

**I am using miniconda3 with python version==3.7.16 with Ubuntu 22.04** and the **error occurs from the library dm-launchpad-nightly.** Can anyone help with this?

[directory where error arises](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZlSQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem with the dependencies; I didn't manage to solve it myself, but stumbled on this github [issue](https://github.com/google-research/google-research/issues/1182) with requirement.txt file with the correct dependencies.